# SQL: Trying to find a way to check for unique values across columns tied to unique identifiers and insert ones that don't exist

Tags: sql

I have a list of unique identifiers with several columns of data. There is also a secondary table with a list of unique restaurants. Each column from the first table has a unique type of restaurant for their given ID. I've been trying to populate some missing data for these but can't find a way to make sure they populate values that don't already exist in other columns.

Below are examples of the data

```
table1 : customer_restaurants
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| c_id  |restaurant1|restaurant2|restaurant3|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |   Mc'Ds   |   BurgerK | Chipotle  |
|   2   |   Carls   |   DairyQ  | McD's     |
|   3   |   Jack    |   NULL    | Chipotle  |
|   4   |   TacoBell|   NULL    |  NULL     |
|   5   |   Null    |   NULL    |  NULL     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

table2: restaurant_list
+-------+-----------+
| r_id  |restaurants|
+-------+-----------+
|   A   |   Mc'Ds   |  
|   B   |   Carls   |  
|   C   |   Jack    | 
|   D   |   TacoBell| 
|   E   |   DairyQ  | 
|   F   |   Chipotle| 
|   G   |   DelTaco | 
|   H   |   BurgerK | 
+-------+-----------+
```

I messed with cases and that didn't work. Currently, I've tried updating the table using coalesces but the obvious problem is that I can't figure out how to cycle through the columns to make sure the values are unique. My results for the nulls end up just repeating the same value, which is Mc'Ds for every null.

```
UPDATE customer_restaurants
SET restaurant1 = COALESCE(restaurant1, restaurant_list.restaurants),
    restaurant2 = COALESCE(restaurant2, restaurant_list.restaurants),
    restaurant3 = COALESCE(restaurant3, restaurant_list.restaurants)
FROM (
    SELECT restaurants, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY restaurants) AS row_num
    FROM restaurant_list
) AS restaurant_list
WHERE
    (restaurant1 IS NULL AND row_num = 1) OR
    (restaurant2 IS NULL AND row_num = 2) OR
    (restaurant3 IS NULL AND row_num = 3) ;
```

```
how the table should look
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| c_id  |restaurant1|restaurant2|restaurant3|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |   Mc'Ds   |   BurgerK | Chipotle  |
|   2   |   Carls   |   DairyQ  | McD's     |
|   3   |   Jack    |   Mc'Ds   | Chipotle  |
|   4   |   TacoBell|   Mc'Ds   |  Carls    |
|   5   |   Mc'Ds   |   Carls   |  Jack     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: i really can't understand the logic of your result, Mc'Ds is douled in restarant1 and 2 there is nothing unique about it agy should customer 4 goto carls, maybe he doesn't like like icecream

Comment: A restaurant can repeat in a field but not in multiple fields for same record. A stored procedure might get what you want. I would code it with VBA in Access. Normalizing table1 might make it easier. Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: What happens when you have 27 restaurants

Comment: @nbk I’m trying to get uniques across the columns. So even though category one has multiple Mc’Ds, they’re unique for the IDs. I’m trying to find a way to make it unique by userID, horizontally

Comment: @june7 trying to do this with just sql. I’m not familiar with checking across a range of fields for uniques

Comment: @stu I’m just using a smaller data set for now, but it should operate the same. I’m thinking of just checking against the list of restaurants and then placing the first one that does not exist for the ID

Answer (score 0):

So after much thought.

I came up with following

First we need a CTE so that we have a fixed set of rows and row_numbers, so that we can add always the same rows of restaurant_list

Next the update should only occur when there is oat least one restaurant missing.

Additional we need to eliminate all existing restaurant that are in that row which is done by `NOT IN ( SELECT res FROM( SELECT restaurant1 res UNION SELECT restaurant2 UNION SELECT restaurant3) a  WHERE res IS NOT NULL)`

So the rest should be select athe row_num and is fetched with `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`  which takes the first element of cte that is not present in the row

changing the order of the rownumber in the CTE would let you adept which restaurants should be selected first here McDs(if nit already present in that row)

This would have a fixed position for example for Jack restaurant3 (if Jack is not present in  that row.
Every thing more complicated, you should do in a programming langauge that is better suited

```
CREATE TABLE customer_restaurants
    (c_id int, restaurant1 varchar(8), restaurant2 varchar(8), restaurant3 varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO customer_restaurants
    (c_id, restaurant1, restaurant2, restaurant3)
VALUES
    (1, 'Mc''Ds', 'BurgerK', 'Chipotle'),
    (2, 'Carls', 'DairyQ', 'McD''s'),
    (3, 'Jack', NULL, 'Chipotle'),
    (4, 'TacoBell', NULL, NULL),
    (5, NULL, NULL, NULL)
;


CREATE TABLE restaurant_list
    (r_id varchar(1), restaurants varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO restaurant_list
    (r_id, restaurants)
VALUES
    ('A', 'Mc''Ds'),
    ('B', 'Carls'),
    ('C', 'Jack'),
    ('D', 'TacoBell'),
    ('E', 'DairyQ'),
    ('F', 'Chipotle'),
    ('G', 'DelTaco'),
    ('H', 'BurgerK')
;
```

```
WITH CTE as(
      SELECT restaurants, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r_id) AS row_num
    FROM restaurant_list)
UPDATE customer_restaurants
SET restaurant1 = COALESCE(restaurant1, (SELECT restaurants 
  FROM CTE WHERE restaurants NOT IN (
  SELECT res FROM(
  SELECT restaurant1 res UNION SELECT restaurant2
  UNION SELECT restaurant3) a  WHERE res IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY row_num ASC
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0))
  ,
    restaurant2 = COALESCE(restaurant2, (SELECT restaurants 
  FROM CTE WHERE restaurants NOT IN (
  SELECT res FROM(
  SELECT restaurant1 res UNION SELECT restaurant2
  UNION SELECT restaurant3) a  WHERE res IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY row_num ASC
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1))
  ,
    restaurant3 = COALESCE(restaurant3, (SELECT restaurants 
  FROM CTE WHERE restaurants NOT IN (
  SELECT res FROM(
  SELECT restaurant1 res UNION SELECT restaurant2
  UNION SELECT restaurant3) a  WHERE res IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY row_num ASC
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2))


WHERE
    (restaurant1 IS NULL  ) OR
    (restaurant2 IS NULL ) OR
    (restaurant3 IS NULL ) ;
```

> ```
> UPDATE 3
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM customer_restaurants
```

| c_id | restaurant1 | restaurant2 | restaurant3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mc'Ds | BurgerK | Chipotle |
| 2 | Carls | DairyQ | McD's |
| 3 | Jack | Carls | Chipotle |
| 4 | TacoBell | Carls | Jack |
| 5 | Mc'Ds | Carls | Jack |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8nerrdMW)

Answer (score 0):

```
with rest as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by r_id) as rn
    from restaurant_list
), pool as (
    select
        min(case when rn = 1 then restaurants end) as pool1,
        min(case when rn = 2 then restaurants end) as pool2,
        min(case when rn = 3 then restaurants end) as pool3
    from rest
    where rn <= 3
)
update customer_list set
    restaurant1 =
        case when restaurant1 is not null then restaurant1 else (                
            select coalesce(
                case when pool1 in (restaurant2, restaurant3) then null else pool1 end,
                case when pool2 in (restaurant2, restaurant3) then null else pool2 end,
                case when pool3 in (restaurant2, restaurant3) then null else pool3 end
            ) from pool) end,
    restaurant2 =
        case when restaurant2 is not null then restaurant2 else (
            select coalesce(
                case when pool1 in (coalesce(restaurant1, pool1), restaurant3) then null else pool1 end,
                case when pool2 in (coalesce(restaurant1, pool1), restaurant3) then null else pool2 end,
                case when pool3 in (coalesce(restaurant1, pool1), restaurant3) then null else pool3 end
            ) from pool) end,
    restaurant3 =
        case when restaurant3 is not null then restaurant3 else (
            select coalesce(
                case when pool1 in (coalesce(restaurant1, pool1), coalesce(restaurant1, pool2), coalesce(restaurant2, pool1), coalesce(restaurant2, pool2)) then null else pool1 end,
                case when pool2 in (coalesce(restaurant1, pool1), coalesce(restaurant1, pool2), coalesce(restaurant2, pool1), coalesce(restaurant2, pool2)) then null else pool2 end,
                case when pool3 in (coalesce(restaurant1, pool1), coalesce(restaurant1, pool2), coalesce(restaurant2, pool1), coalesce(restaurant2, pool2)) then null else pool3 end
            ) from pool) end;
```

It's not the most elegant or readily extensible beyond three columns. It does get the job done though in a single pass and it's straightforward to understand.

If you did want to update the columns individually then you could simplify/eliminate a lot of the complication. See the linked fiddle for an example.

https://dbfiddle.uk/hr3FDnQq

Answer (score 0):

The task seemed somewhat strange at first. However, the solution is not as simple as it first seemed. It was interesting. Example for SQL Server.

```
-- test data
create table customer_restaurants (c_id int,restaurant1 varchar(20)
  ,restaurant2 varchar(20),restaurant3 varchar(20));
insert  into customer_restaurants values
 (1   ,   'Mc''Ds' ,    'BurgerK' , 'Chipotle')
,(2   ,   'Carls'   ,   'DairyQ'  , 'McD''s')
,(3   ,   'Jack'    ,   NULL    , 'Chipotle')
,(4   ,   'TacoBell',   NULL    ,  NULL     )
,(5   ,   Null      ,   NULL    ,  NULL     );
create table restaurant_list(r_id varchar(1),restaurants varchar(20));
insert into restaurant_list values
 ('A','Mc''Ds')
,('B','Carls')
,('C','Jack')
,('D','TacoBell')
,('E','DairyQ')
,('F','Chipotle')
,('G','DelTaco')
,('H','BurgerK');
```

--update query

```
UPDATE customer_restaurants 
SET customer_restaurants.restaurant1 = rst1 
   ,customer_restaurants.restaurant2 = rst2 
   ,customer_restaurants.restaurant3 = rst3 
output inserted.*,deleted.*,t3.rst1,t3.rst2,t3.rst3
from customer_restaurants inner join (
select * 
     ,case when t2.restaurant3 is not null then t2.restaurant3
      else (select top 1 restaurants from restaurant_list l 
                where l.restaurants not in(rst1,rst2,coalesce(t2.restaurant3,''))
               order by l.r_id)
      end rst3
from(
   select * 
     ,case when t1.restaurant2 is not null then t1.restaurant2
      else (select top 1 restaurants from restaurant_list l 
                where l.restaurants not in(rst1
                             ,coalesce(t1.restaurant2,''),coalesce(t1.restaurant3,''))
               order by l.r_id)
      end rst2
   from(select * 
          ,case when c1.restaurant1 is not null then c1.restaurant1
           else(select top 1 restaurants from restaurant_list l 
                  where l.restaurants not in(coalesce(c1.restaurant1,'')
                               ,coalesce(c1.restaurant2,''),coalesce(c1.restaurant3,''))
                 order by l.r_id)
           end rst1
        from customer_restaurants c1
     where restaurant1 is null or restaurant2 is null or restaurant3 is null
     )t1
   )t2
)t3 on t3.c_id=customer_restaurants.c_id;
```

Result (draft with output inserted.*,deleted.*)

------------inserted (updated)------------------|---------------deleted---------------------------|-----calculated-----------

| c_id | restaurant1 | restaurant2 | restaurant3 | c_id | restaurant1 | restaurant2 | restaurant3 | rst1 | rst2 | rst3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Jack | Mc'Ds | Chipotle | 3 | Jack | null | Chipotle | Jack | Mc'Ds | Chipotle |
| 4 | TacoBell | Mc'Ds | Carls:- | 4 | TacoBell | null | null | TacoBell | Mc'Ds | Carls |
| 5 | Mc'Ds | Carls | Jack | 5 | null | null | null | Mc'Ds | Carls | Jack |

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qK_UzoXo)